# Why are there extra lines of code in terminal with bash on OSX Catalina?

Tags: bash, macos, macos-catalina

When running my code I seem to be getting a lot of extra lines of code in the terminal.

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has replaced bash shell with zsh shell. So this is just a I or information statement being printed out by the system. If you want to use zsh shell instead of the older bash shell you can follow those steps. However, in order to silence this warning and continue to use bash itself, you can add this command to ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile:

```
export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1
```

You have to open bash_profile file with a text editor add the above line and then save it.
Use any text editor of your choice,

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
mate ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just was able to fix this issue... For anyone else having htis issue, this article helped a bit also: "https://medium.com/fbdevclagos/updating-visual-studio-code-default-terminal-shell-from-bash-to-zsh-711c40d6f8dc"

Comment: Sorry, one more question... This is still showing up in the terminal... %                                                                                                                                                               
jakeboutin@Jakes-MacBook-Pro ~ % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/jakeboutin/Desktop/Programing/Ex_Files_Learning_Python/Exercise Files/Ch2/classes_start.py"
myClass method2 This is a string
jakeboutin@Jakes-MacBook-Pro ~ %

Comment: Looks like it's printing the destination of the file. This probably another setting change right?

Comment: It’s showing the path to the code you ran just like you would type in manually in terminal when not using vs code

Comment: There is nothing old about bash or brand new about zsh -- they are just two different shells.